# New Project Creation Not Working on Mavensmate

Tags: metadata, ide, mavensmate

I am using a Windows 7, 64 bit system with Sublime Text 3 build 3065 and Mavensmate version 4.0.2

My user settings are as below.

```
"mm_workspace" : "c:\mymavenprojects",
"mm_http_proxy" : "http:\/\/web-proxy.company.com:8080",
"mm_https_proxy" : "http:\/\/web-proxy.company.com:8080",
"mm_api_version" : "31.0"
```

I have setup the proxies in environment variables as well. I have tried running the app as an administrator also but it doesn't resolve this problem.

I couldn't trace any error in the logs as well. Here is the log extract:

```
MAVENSMATE: Loading MavensMate for Sublime Text
[MAVENSMATE UI]: starting local MavensMate UI server
MAVENSMATE: mm_installer -->
MAVENSMATE: Calling mm_interface
MAVENSMATE: OPERATION: new_project

MAVENSMATE: checking for updated mm version
MAVENSMATE: mm command: MAVENSMATE: mm is up to date (0.2.4), no further action needed

MAVENSMATE: "C:\Users\guptapat\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\MavensMate\mm\mm.exe" --ui -o new_project -c SUBLIME_TEXT_3

Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2014-12-08 13:58:11, next run at 2014-12-08 14:58:11 or after
MAVENSMATE: response from mm: {

"body": "UI Generated Successfully", 


"body_type": "text", 


"success": true, 


"time": "1.2899999618530273"
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this finally. The solution is very weird though. All this while I was trying to use IE v10 to create new project. For a change I used Chrome and it started working magically.

Answer (score -1):

My settings on proxy are empty and t works fine for me. can you try setting the proxy settings to null?

Comment: Well that's the catch. I would want to use it with the proxy setting itself. I am working from a private company network and need to use proxy server for any api calls to SFDC.